# Ftp outbound adapter | Fails to write to ftp

Tags: spring-boot, ftp, spring-integration

```
@EnableIntegration
@Configuration
public class RtwEmploymentComplianceFlow {


@Bean
DefaultFtpSessionFactory rtwFtpFileSessionFactory() {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();

    sf.setPort(21);
    sf.setUsername("a-asdf");
    sf.setPassword("asdf@123");
    sf.setHost("asdf.ftp.org");

    return sf;
}

@Autowired
TiffToPdfConverter tiffToPdf;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow rtwFlow(
        @Value("${rtw-input-directory}") File rtwFolder, DefaultFtpSessionFactory rtwFtpFileSessionFactory) {
    GenericTransformer<File, Message<String>> pdfFileConverter = (File source) -> {

        return MessageBuilder.withPayload("hello").setHeader(FileHeaders.FILENAME, source.getName().split("\\.")[0] + ".txt").build();
    };

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Files.inboundAdapter(rtwFolder)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                    .preventDuplicates(true)
                    .patternFilter("*.tif"), 
                    poller -> poller.poller(pm -> pm.fixedDelay(1000)))
            .transform(File.class, pdfFileConverter)
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(rtwFtpFileSessionFactory)
                        .remoteDirectory("Guru")
                        .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                        .fileNameGenerator(message -> {
                            Object o = message.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.FILENAME);
                            String fileName = String.class.cast(o);
                            System.out.println("output FileName is: " + fileName);

                            return fileName;
                        })
                    )
            .get();     
    }
}
```

The code above begins to create a sample.txt.writing file in the ftp site, but the size remains 0KB for about 15 seconds and then the file disappears.

There are no exceptions raised.

Not sure why the ftp fails to write the file completely. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this has got to do something with clientMode, I tried setting it to 2 and got a connection timeout exception. Can someone explain what this setting is?

Comment: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html Generally speaking, passive is needed if there are firewalls involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Gary for your feedback.

Finally settled it with following:

1. factory.setClientMode(2)   -- passive mode
2. firewall (windows firewall), allowed 0-65000 ports (outbound) for TCP on the ftp server

worked like a charm.